# How to deal with imperfect multicollinearity

Tags: nonlinear-regression, multicollinearity

I am estimating a model for an assignment, and found out that there is a 0.9 correlation between two of the independent variables. So If I am not wrong I should omit one variable and redo the regression. However, it is asked to me, to estimate the log-log model and then the correlation between variables drop from 0.9 to 0.5. so in the new model, should I still omit one of the variables? 
Also, which should be the cut-off in order to decide where I should omit a variable? Is 0.6 correlation high enough to give problems to the model?